# Identity in database and on entity level is not identity in breeze metadata

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, breeze

I have two entities, BlogEntry and BlogBody, both set up in the same way but BlogEntry ID field is not identity according to breeze metadata. I don't understand why.

What I did so far:

- I tried to change the mapping data and not using fluent api, just using only fluent api, or mixing the annotations and fluent api. **Result**: always the same
- double-check the IIS settings (does it read that content I'm working on? etc.) **result**: everything seems ok but the result is the same
- double-check the database files (I'm using database project to manage the database part). **Result**: everything seems ok, identities are set up, SQL manager says both table has identity set up but the result always the same
- clean project - rebuild project. **Result**: always the same
- IIS reset. **Result**: always the same
- Disable Chrome cache. **Result**: always the same
- Another browser. **Result**: always the same
- Googling around... I've found a [blog](http://blog.ozippy.com/2014/06/breeze-angular-and-entity-framework.html) about the same error and the same phenomenon but no more info described there.

I've run out of thoughts. I would like to ask some help what to do and how to have the ID field of BlogEntry entity as Identity in metadata!

Db tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BLOG_BODY](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BODY_WITH_MARKUP] [text] NOT NULL,
    [BODY_WITHOUT_MARKUP] [text] NULL,
    [BLOG_ENTRY_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CREATE_DATE] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [CREATED_BY] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((1)),
    [LAST_CHANGED_DATE] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [LAST_CHANGED_BY] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((1)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.BLOG_BODY] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 75) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BLOG_BODY]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Blog_Body__Blog_Entry_Id] FOREIGN KEY([BLOG_ENTRY_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[BLOG_ENTRY] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BLOG_BODY] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Blog_Body__Blog_Entry_Id]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BLOG_ENTRY](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TITLE] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [IS_PUBLISHED] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [AUTHOR_ID] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((1)),
    [CREATE_DATE] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [CREATED_BY] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((1)),
    [LAST_CHANGED_DATE] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [LAST_CHANGED_BY] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((1)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.BLOG_ENTRY] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 75) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Entities:

```c#
public class BlogBody
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string BodyWithMarkup { get; set; }

        public string BodyWithoutMarkup { get; set; }

        public int BlogEntryId { get; set; }

        public virtual BlogEntry BlogEntry { get; set; }
    }

public class BlogEntry
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int IsPublished { get; set; }

        public virtual BlogBody BlogBody { get; set; }
    }
```

Mapping:

```c#
#region BLOG_ENTRY
            modelBuilder.Entity<BlogEntry>().ToTable("BLOG_ENTRY");
            modelBuilder.Entity<BlogEntry>().HasKey(k => k.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<BlogEntry>().Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
            modelBuilder.Entity<BlogEntry>().Property(t => t.Title).HasColumnName("TITLE");
            modelBuilder.Entity<BlogEntry>().Property(t => t.IsPublished).HasColumnName("IS_PUBLISHED");

            modelBuilder.Entity<BlogEntry>().HasRequired(t => t.BlogBody).WithRequiredDependent(bb => bb.BlogEntry);
            //AUTHOR_ID is not mapped yet
            #endregion

            #region BLOG_BODY
            modelBuilder.Entity<BlogBody>().ToTable("BLOG_BODY");
            modelBuilder.Entity<BlogBody>().HasKey(k => k.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<BlogBody>().Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
            modelBuilder.Entity<BlogBody>().Property(t => t.BodyWithMarkup).HasColumnName("BODY_WITH_MARKUP");
            modelBuilder.Entity<BlogBody>().Property(t => t.BodyWithoutMarkup).HasColumnName("BODY_WITHOUT_MARKUP");
            modelBuilder.Entity<BlogBody>().Property(t => t.BlogEntryId).HasColumnName("BLOG_ENTRY_ID");
```

[image: Breeze metadata]

Comment: In the sql above check those primary key constraint definitions.

Comment: @Andrew: everything is ok with them, SQL Studio says that both column are Identity column and primary keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data model and mapping do not match. Let's look at the mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BlogEntry>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.BlogBody)
            .WithRequiredDependent(bb => bb.BlogEntry);
```

This is a one-to-one association. Entity Framework expects this to be implemented by a `BlogEntry` table that has a non-identity primary key that is also a foreign key to `BlogBody`'s primary key (that may or may not be identity, whatever you like). So it's EF that "screws up" the meta data of the identity field, it just doesn't assume it's there and it doesn't do anything to confirm that (it's code first, after all).

But I don't think this is the kind of association you intend. If you want this to be a 1:1 association at all, a `BlogEntry` is more likely to be the principle entity (the one that can exist on its own). That's also what the data model expresses.

But then `BlogBody` should have the non-identity PK/FK and you should modify the data model accordingly.

If, on the other hand, the data model is leading/immutable, the only thing you can do is map this as a regular one-to-many association...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BlogEntry>()
            .HasMany(be => be.BlogBodies)
            .WithRequired(bb => bb.BlogEntry)
            .HasForeignKey(bb => bb.BlogEntryId);
```

...and enforce by business rules that the number of `BlogBodies` cannot be > 1.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! You are right, `BlogEntry` is the principal and the other one is the dependent. When I checked the EF documentation about one-to-one relations I did not understand why both entity don't have primary keys. Now I start to understand what the situation is and I have to spend more time to be more familiar with EF. 

I modified my data structure accordingly and it works now. Thanks for your help again!